# AWS CDK: Adding new stack not working (not showing up)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am trying to add a new stack into the existing cloudformation infrastructure. But for some reason, the new stack is not getting deployed along with other stacks.

When I deploy this new stack separately, it works properly.

Here's the code:

**FILE1.ts**

```
export class newStack extends Construct {

    readonly oneStack: OneStack;

    readonly twoStack: TwoStack;

    readonly myNewStack: MyNewStack;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: someProps) {
        super(scope, id);

        const { env, region, stageSetting } = props;

        this.oneStack = new OneStack(this, `${id}-OneStack`, {
            ...props,
            stackName: `${id}-ABCDEFG`,
        });

        this.twoStack = new TwoStack(scope, `${id}-TwoStack`,{
            ...props,
        });

        this.myNewStack = new MyNewStack(this, `${id}-Alarms`, {
            ...props,
        });
    }
}
```

**FILE2.ts**

```
deploymentgrps.push({
            name: "name"
            stacks: [
                newStack.oneStack,
                newStack.twoStack,
                newStack.myNewStackStack,
            ],
            deploymentRule: "rules here"
        });

regularDeploymentGroupOpts.forEach((grp_member) => pipeline.addDeploymentGroup(grp_member))
```

In other file, upon doing

> const abc = new newStack()

all stacks should be generated, is my understanding.
On deploying the CDK change, myNewStack is not getting deployed like oneStack and twoStack. Does anyone see anything that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check a list of stack that you will deploy.

```
cdk ls
```

For example:

```
oneStack
twoStack
myNewStack
```

Then you want to deploy all stacks:

```
cdk deploy oneStack twoStack myNewStack
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
What I am trying is, inside "newStack", I have defined/created all other Stacks. Probably my naming is confusing. "newStack" is a construct. So initially, there were two stacks inside "newStack". And upon doing 

"deploy:assets myNewStack && brazil-build cdk deploy myNewStack", both the stacks used to get deployed.

But when I added myNewStack, that does not happpen. It still onlyconsiders those first two stacks.

Comment: what is output when you `cdk diff`

Comment: I see all the things that I am actually creating inside myNewStack when I do `cdk diff`

For example: `AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm Alarm1`, `AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm Alarm2`..

Comment: you are right. I had to deploy the stacks separately just as you mentioned in the answer. I was expecting that, since I am adding them in the deployment group, they should be deployed. But for my cloud-account, I need to deploy manually. Thanks for the help.